# delete CSV file row based on the value of a column in command line

Tags: csv, unix, awk, command

here is how my dataset looks like, I am trying to filter out country that the 4th column is >= 1000.

```
Marshall Islands,53127,77,41
Vanuatu,276244,25,70
Solomon Islands,611343,23,142
Sao Tome and Principe,204327,72,147
Belize,374681,46,171
Maldives,436330,39,172
Guyana,777859,27,206
Eswatini,1367254,24,323
Timor-Leste,1296311,30,392
Lesotho,2233339,28,619
Guinea-Bissau,1861283,43,799
Namibia,2533794,49,1242
Gambia,2100568,61,1273
.
.
.
Zimbabwe,16529904,32,5329
```

(total 77 lines of data)

I have tried to run the following command on my terminal, but it only output 1 line of the dataset to new file.

```
awk -F, '$4 > 999' original.csv > new.csv
```

*update, all line except Zimbabwe are ending with ^M$.

Here is desired output

```
Namibia,2533794,49,1242
Gambia,2100568,61,1273
Burundi,10864245,13,1380
Armenia,2930450,63,1849
Rwanda,12208407,17,2091
Mongolia,3075647,68,2103
Kyrgyzstan,6045117,36,2184
Mauritania,4420184,53,2335
Lao People's Democratic Republic,6858160,34,2357
Liberia,4731906,51,2399
Tajikistan,8921343,27,2407
Sierra Leone,7557212,42,3147
Togo,7797694,41,3210
Chad,14899994,23,3406
Congo,5260750,66,3496
Cambodia,16005373,23,3678
Paraguay,6811297,61,4175
El Salvador,6377853,71,4546
Guinea,12717176,36,4552
Benin,11175692,47,5227
Zimbabwe,16529904,32,5329
Azerbaijan,9827589,55,5439
Burkina Faso,19193383,29,5517
Nepal,29304998,19,5666
Haiti,10981229,54,5968
Somalia,14742523,44,6544
Zambia,17094131,43,7346
Senegal,15850567,47,7409
Bolivia (Plurinational State of),11051600,69,7634
Mali,18541980,42,7708
Tunisia,11532127,69,7916
Guatemala,16913504,51,8572
Dominican Republic,10766998,80,8643
Cuba,11484636,77,8841
Afghanistan,35530082,25,8971
Syrian Arab Republic,18269867,54,9774
Uganda,42862957,23,9942
Yemen,28250420,36,10175
Kazakhstan,18204498,57,10438
Ecuador,16624857,64,10585
Côte d'Ivoire,24294750,50,12227
Kenya,49699863,27,13201
Cameroon,24053727,56,13416
Sudan,40533328,34,13931
Ghana,28833629,55,15976
Myanmar,53370609,30,16183
United Republic of Tanzania,57310020,33,18943
Angola,29784193,65,19312
Ethiopia,104957438,20,21317
Peru,32165484,78,24999
Iraq,38274617,70,26899
Algeria,41318141,72,29771
Viet Nam,95540797,35,33643
Thailand,69037516,49,33966
Democratic Republic of the Congo,81339984,44,35692
South Africa,56717156,66,37348
Colombia,49065613,80,39471
Egypt,97553148,43,41660
Philippines,104918094,47,48978
Bangladesh,164669750,36,59047
Pakistan,197015953,36,71797
Nigeria,190886313,50,94525
Mexico,129163273,80,103159
Indonesia,263991375,55,144295
India,1339180125,34,449965
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your Input_file's last field may have spaces in it. You can also check it by doing `cat -e Input_file` it will show you where is line ending including hidden spaces at the line end. If this is the case then try following command.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} $4+0 > 999' Input_file
```

Comment: That wouldn't explain the results the OP claims to be seeing. Trailing spaces would cause a string instead of numeric comparison but in a string comparison `5329` is less than `999` so that can't be the problem.

Comment: @EdMorton, yeah, but I thought may be OP simply pasted output from more of OP's input, let's op confirm on same, as always thank you for bringing nice point Sir 

Comment: I checked, the line are ending with "^M$", but your code does work!

Comment: That doesn't make sense given the example in your question but if that IS the problem then all you need is `$4+0 > 999`, no need for the `gsub()`.

Comment: But like @EdMorton said, I still don't understand what is causing my issue. thx for you answer anyway!

Comment: @cyw, your welcome. I have updated my code(as per Ed sir's suggestions)  to handle both spaces and control M characters. Please check it. Also as per Ed sir's comment under question section kindly edit your question with right expected output and let us know then.

Comment: @cyw if you post a [mcve] with concise,  testable, textual sample input and the expected output given that input (and state that you have DOS line endings) then we can help you.

Comment: "$4+0 > 999" did solve the problem, is there any reason why its working? I do find that while every line is ending with "^M$", only Zimbabwe is ending with "$".

Comment: @cyw, yes because it means keep only digits from starting to till anything else comes(what +0 will do). That's why it's working. Request you to please edit your question with correct expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: @EdMorton ok, let me check how to do it. I'm new to StackOverflow here. Still big thx for both of your help!

Comment: All you need to do is replace the ellipses (`...`s) in your sample input with the Zimbabwe line from your posted output and then state that all lines except the last end with `^M`. Then it'll all make sense.